# Why is bash confusing this HEREDOC limit string as a command?

Tags: bash, here-document

I am trying to use nested HEREDOC blocks in a bash script.
Note

- The outer HEREDOC is user to run a list of commands as a different user via `sudo`
- the inner HEREDOC is capturing regular text to `cat` into a file.

```sh
# run some commands as regular user
sudo -s -u $reg_user << EOF
echo "installing Pathogen plugin manager"
mkdir -p ~/.vim/autoload ~/.vim/bundle && \
curl -LSso ~/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim https://tpo.pe/pathogen.vim

# start the nested HEREDOC
#-----------------------------
#
echo "configuring \.vimrc"
cat <<-VRC >> ~/.vimrc
    "
    "======================================================
    " vim core settings
    "======================================================
    "
    " show numbers - to turn off :set nonumber
    set number

    " always show status bar
    set laststatus=2
VRC # limit string to close the inner HEREDOC

echo "more bash commands"

EOF # end the outer HEREDOC - NOTE: this is also the end of the 
    # entire script itself
```

When this script runs, the output is:

> /bin/bash: line 229: EOF: command not found

Why does bash think this `EOF` is a command and not the HEREDOC delimit string

- Im not sure if the white spaces between the beginning of the lines and the limit strings matter - if so let me know and I'll try to explain

update: here is a simplfied version of the script which has copy and pastable runnable code - that seems to produce the same-ish error

```
#! /bin/bash

# If you want to run this code you need to assign a valid user here
user="non-root user"

# run some commands as regular user
sudo -s -u $user << EOF
echo "installing plugins"
mkdir -p testdir

# start the nested HEREDOC
#-----------------------------
#
echo "configuring \.config_file"
cat <<-VRC >> /tmp/test_vimrc
    "
    "======================================================
    " vim core settings
    "======================================================
    "
    " show numbers - to turn off :set nonumber
    set number

    " always show status bar
    set laststatus=2
VRC 

echo "more bash commands"

EOF
```

output error is:

> /bin/bash: line 22: warning: here-document at line 8 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `VRC')

Comment: the `-` in the  HEREDOC  command is like a switch to tell HEREDOC to ignore tabs ,  it shouldn't be considered part of the HEREDOC delimiter

Comment: I assume the comments aren't part of the actual file? You should [edit] them out, since at the moment your code actually exhibits a different error than what you're asking about. Please post a working example that demonstrates the behaviour in question.

Comment: yes, I was adding comments as part of the post - to try and make the code easier to understand. And yes the script is a simplified version of the real script. I am currently testing another version that runs and produces the error as you requested. If I get it working I will post as an update to the existing code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a space after `VRC`.  Remove it.

Comment: Oh really - I cant have any content after the delimit string?

Comment: No, @the_velour_fog, the delimiter must be the only thing on the line, in order to make parsing easier, and to prevent accidental false positives.